# J meter with Python : how to import the packages

Tags: python, jmeter

Iam new bee to the jmeter

My code is working in the Python 2.7 with importing additional packages Dateutil, parser .

Problme : But when I am trying to run same code in the J Meter-JSR-223 PreProcessors , an error saying No module named dateutil in.

So , I have tried another approach to use Jython .

Installed the Jython ( downloaded the dateutil) and provide the packages reference under

```
import sys
sys.path.append('C:/Jython27/Lib/site-packages')
sys.path.append('C:/Jython27/Lib/site-packages/python_dateutil-2.4.2-py2.7/dateutil')
sys.path.append('C:/Jython27/Lib/site-packages/python_dateutil-2.4.2-py2.7/dateutil')
```

Now packages error is gone but string syntax error is present `. 
java.sql.Date' object has no attribute .`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe [dateutil](https://pypi.org/project/python-dateutil/) package can be picked up from CPython as it doesn't require any extra wrappers for Java.

1. Install dateutil normally using [`pip`](https://pypi.org/project/pip/) like:

   ```
   pip install python-dateutil
   ```
2. Add `site-packages` folder of Python (not Jython) installation to [sys.path](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sys.html#sys.path) like:

   ```
   sys.path.append("C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages")
   ```
3. That's it, now you should be able to use `dateutil` module functions from the JSR223 Test Elements:

   [image]

---

Be aware that invoking Python scripts via [Jython](http://www.jython.org/) interpreter is not the best idea from performance perspective and if you're about to invoke your Python code only limited number of times and/or with a single thread - it might be better to go for the [OS Process Sampler](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#OS_Process_Sampler).

If you plan to use the Python code to create the main load - consider using [Locust](https://locust.io/) tool instead of JMeter. If you don't want to change JMeter a good approach would be rewriting your Python code in [Groovy](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black) - it will be way better from the performance perspective.

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot help without seeing your code, the error itself doesn't tell the full story

Comment: can you please provide sample values in the oS sampler if I want to execute the above code. Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

hi please find follwing

```
import sys
sys.path.append('C:/Python27/Lib/site-packages')
sys.path.append('C:/Python27/Lib/site-packages/python_dateutil-2.4.2-py2.7/dateutil')

from dateutil.parser import *
sourceDateTimeOfEvent = ""
dateTimeOfEvent = ""

a=parse('2016-07-01 13:00:00')
sourceDateTimeOfEvent = a.isoformat()+"+05:30Z"
dateTimeOfEvent = a.isoformat()+ "Z"

vars.put("sourceDateTimeOfEvent", sourceDateTimeOfEvent)
vars.put("dateTimeOfEvent", dateTimeOfEvent)
```

This sourceDateTimeOfEvent and dateTimeOfEvent considered as two variables and passed it to the json file